# Changing the light state

Tags: software

Can someone give me a solution to the following problem?
I have 1 IR remote, blynk app,some pushButtons and also 1 relay module.
(I set 1 pin of ATMega as input to be able to read what esp sends when I use the blynk app).
So basically what I want to do is this:
If I press btn1 from the IR Remote or PushBtn nr1, or I send 1 from blynk app
then relay 1 must turn on. For now that part works.
Anyway, what I want to do next is this:
If the relay is turned on (closed) I want to be able to turn it off using the same buttons (for which I have set a counter and I call that variable).
Now I can turn the relay off only if I use the same btn that previously I have used to turn it on. But I want to be able to turn it off the other way.
If I used the blynk app to turn it on then if I press the pushbtn second time - I want it to be off. Also if I don't press the pushbtn but I use the IR remote and press 1 2 times- the relay should be off.

```
if(cntbtn2 == 1 || cntPushbtn2 == 1)
      {
      digitalWrite(rel2,LOW);
      u8g.setFont(u8g_font_courB10);
      u8g.drawStr(32,10,"Interior");
      u8g.drawFrame(0,12,128,51);
      u8g.drawLine(64,12,64,62);

      if(cntbtn1 == 1 || cntPushbtn1 == 1)
          {
          u8g.setFont(u8g_font_5x8);
          u8g.drawStr(10,23,"Sufragerie");
          u8g.drawStr(15,60,"L.aprinsa");
          u8g.drawBitmapP( 20, 8, 16, 64, LightOn); 
          }

      else if(cntbtn1 != 1)
          {
          u8g.setFont(u8g_font_5x8);
          u8g.drawStr(10,23,"Sufragerie");
          u8g.drawStr(15,60,"L.stinsa");
          u8g.drawBitmapP( 20, 8, 16, 64, LightOff); 
          }  

      u8g.drawStr(73,23,"Dormitor");
      u8g.drawStr(75,60,"L.aprinsa");
      u8g.drawBitmapP( 78, 7, 16, 64, LightOn);
      }

else if(cntbtn2 == 2)
    {     
    if(cntbtn1 == 1 || cntPushbtn1 == 1)
        {
        u8g.setFont(u8g_font_courB10);
        u8g.drawStr(32,10,"Interior");
        u8g.drawFrame(0,12,128,51);
        u8g.drawLine(64,12,64,62);
        u8g.setFont(u8g_font_5x8);
        u8g.drawStr(10,23,"Sufragerie");
        u8g.drawStr(15,60,"L.aprinsa");
        u8g.drawBitmapP( 20, 8, 16, 64, LightOn);  
        u8g.drawStr(73,23,"Dormitor");
        u8g.drawStr(75,60,"L.stinsa");
        u8g.drawBitmapP( 78, 7, 16, 64, LightOff);
        }
    else{
        digitalWrite(rel2,HIGH);
        u8g.setFont(u8g_font_courB10);
        u8g.drawStr(32,10,"Interior");
        u8g.drawFrame(0,12,128,51);
        u8g.drawLine(64,12,64,62);
        u8g.setFont(u8g_font_5x8);
        u8g.drawStr(10,23,"Sufragerie");
        u8g.drawStr(15,60,"L.stinsa");
        u8g.drawBitmapP( 20, 8, 16, 64, LightOff);  
        u8g.drawStr(73,23,"Dormitor");
        u8g.drawStr(75,60,"L.stinsa");
        u8g.drawBitmapP( 78, 7, 16, 64, LightOff);
        }
    }

if(cntbtn2 == 1 && cntPushbtn2 == 2)
    {
    digitalWrite(rel2,HIGH);
    }

//ecran stanga
if(cntbtn1 == 1 || digitalRead(espPin) == 1 || cntPushbtn1 == 1)
    {
    digitalWrite(rel1,LOW);
    u8g.setFont(u8g_font_courB10);
    u8g.drawStr(32,10,"Interior");
    u8g.drawFrame(0,12,128,51);
    u8g.drawLine(64,12,64,62);
    u8g.setFont(u8g_font_5x8);
    u8g.drawStr(10,23,"Sufragerie");
    u8g.drawStr(15,60,"L.aprinsa");
    u8g.drawBitmapP( 20, 8, 16, 64, LightOn);
    if(cntbtn2 == 1 || cntPushbtn2 == 1)
        {
        u8g.drawStr(73,23,"Dormitor");
        u8g.drawStr(75,60,"L.aprinsa");
        u8g.drawBitmapP( 78, 7, 16, 64, LightOn);   
        }
    else
        {
        u8g.drawStr(73,23,"Dormitor");
        u8g.drawStr(75,60,"L.stinsa");
        u8g.drawBitmapP( 78, 7, 16, 64, LightOff); 
        }

   }

else if(cntbtn1 == 2)
    {
    digitalWrite(rel1,HIGH);
    u8g.setFont(u8g_font_courB10);
    u8g.drawStr(32,10,"Interior");
    u8g.drawFrame(0,12,128,51);
    u8g.drawLine(64,12,64,62);
    u8g.setFont(u8g_font_5x8);
    u8g.drawStr(10,23,"Sufragerie");
    u8g.drawStr(15,60,"L.stinsa");
    u8g.drawBitmapP( 20, 8, 16, 64, LightOff); 
    if(cntbtn2 == 1 || cntPushbtn2 == 1)
        {
        u8g.drawStr(73,23,"Dormitor");
        u8g.drawStr(75,60,"L.aprinsa");
        u8g.drawBitmapP( 78, 7, 16, 64, LightOn);   
        }
        if(cntbtn2 != 1)
            {
            u8g.drawStr(73,23,"Dormitor");
            u8g.drawStr(75,60,"L.stinsa");
            u8g.drawBitmapP( 78, 7, 16, 64, LightOff);   
            }
        }
    else
        {
        digitalWrite(rel1,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(rel2,HIGH);
        u8g.setFont(u8g_font_courB10);
        u8g.drawStr(32,10,"Interior");
        u8g.drawFrame(0,12,128,51);
        u8g.drawLine(64,12,64,62);
        u8g.setFont(u8g_font_5x8);
        u8g.drawStr(10,23,"Sufragerie");
        u8g.drawStr(15,60,"L.stinsa");
        u8g.drawBitmapP( 20, 8, 16, 64, LightOff);  
        u8g.drawStr(73,23,"Dormitor");
        u8g.drawStr(75,60,"L.stinsa");
        u8g.drawBitmapP( 78, 7, 16, 64, LightOff);  
        }
   }
```

Comment: your code is badly formatted ... the indentation is all over the place .... that makes it difficult to follow the program flow ... please fix the indentation

Comment: how should it be? is written in arduino ide. that editor identation is bad.

Comment: Re “_that editor identation is bad_”: the IDE is just a writing tool. It is not responsible for what you write. You are. It is willing to help though, if you ask nicely: “Tools → Auto Format”.

Answer (score 0):

Split the logic and the buttons in separate parts and avoid code duplication.

First step is to determine what should control the relay state:

```
// pseudo code follows
if (pushButton.isPressed() || blinkApp.sentCommand() || conditionAlfa.isMet()) {
  // update condition is met, proceed to state change
  relayState = !relayState; // swap relay state
  updateRelay = true; // activate the part responsible for the change
}
```

Once the new desired state is set, act on the relay and update the screen accordingly:

```
// pseudo code again
if (updateRelay == true) {
  updateRelay = false; // we are now going to update, don’t do it again if not necessary 
  relay.setState(relayState); // update the relay, no matter what was the event source
  screen.drawGraphics(); // update the screen, no matter what was the event source
}
```

If you split the two parts you start operating on logical conditions rather than on physical events, making your entire code cleaner and your task simpler.

Comment: i am new in programming and don't know so well many concepts. Also i have a question about the last part of the code you posted. ```if(updateRelay == true){updateRelay = false; }``` that will execute? i mean- the uC it looks at that condition and verify that is it true, but then when enter into the brackets, that condition not became false? and stop executing it?

Comment: `updateRelay` is just a "flag". It doesn't do anything by itself; it's a way to store the fact that the condition had been met. Once it has been tested (by `if (updateRelay == true) {` , its value is no longer needed; the following section will or won't be entered by `if` statement. So making it false again is just "housekeeping" for the next time around. You don't want to keep entering the if-clause after having seen the condition once; only when one of the conditions (button, blynk, etc.) becomes true *again*.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert.